# Meteor application crashing while calling last message

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor, meteor-collections

In one of controller I'm trying to list all online users and their last message. But the browser is unresponsive while running the below code.

In app.js

```
angular.module('jaarvis').controller('OnlineUsersCtrl', ['$scope', '$meteor', function ($scope, $meteor) {
  $scope.$meteorSubscribe('users');
  $scope.$meteorSubscribe('chats');
  var query = {};
  query['status.online'] = true;
  var online = $meteor.collection(function(){
    return Meteor.users.find(query, {fields: {'_id':1, 'profile.name':1, 'status.online':1}});
  });
  $scope.onlineusers = online;

  $scope.getLastMessage = function(userId) {
   var query = {};
   query['uid'] = userId;
   var lastMessage = $meteor.collection(function(){
      return Chats.find({'uid':userId}, {fields: {'content':1}}, {sort: {'_id': -1}, limit: 1});
   });
   return lastMessage;
  };
}]);
```

In HTML

```
<div class="list">

                <a class="item item-avatar" href="/onetoonechat/{{onlineuser._id}}" ng-repeat="onlineuser in onlineusers">
                  <img src="venkman.jpg">
                  <h2>{{onlineuser.profile.name}}</h2>
                  <p>{{ getLastMessage(onlineuser._id) }}</p>
                </a>
              </div>
```

Correct if there is any mistake in my code or provide alternative solution.

Comment: (a) You haven't shown the helper code that creates *onlineuser*. (b) Arguments to helper functions are delimited by spaces, not parentheses so that last `<p>` should be `<p>{{ getLastMessage onlineuser._id  }}</p>` (c) your *getLastMessage* helper returns a cursor of length one (i.e. a *function*) and not a document, the result can't directly be sent to the template without an `#each`.

Comment: I'm using mizzao:user-status for tracking online users. This is will update 'status.online' field whenever user is online. This [link](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-user-status) will provide more information.

Comment: Did you fix (b) and (c) to see if that helped?

Comment: I fixed (b). Now my code in HTML is <p>{{getLastMessage(onlineuser._id)}}</p>. Can you please let me know where and how to fix step (c).

Comment: try getting an object instead of a collection when retrieving your chat message

Comment: (b) Should be `<p>{{getLastMessage onlineuser._id }}</p>`

Comment: Hi Michel, I tried above change but it is throwing below error. Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'onlineuser' is an unexpected token at column 16 of the expression [getLastMessage onlineuser._id] starting at [onlineuser._id].

Comment: The function call is correct @ `{{getLastMessage(onlineuser._id)`, Try creating a meteorpad to demonstrate the issue

Comment: Also be careful about sorting by the `_id` field, since the default Meteor behavior is to generate `_id` [values as random strings](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection) unless otherwise specified.